# Problema a la hora de configurar el dominio con railway.app

Tags: dns, dominio

Hace unos dias hice un proyecto en railway.app y compre un dominio en hostgator.co y al entrar al panel de railway.app me da unos registros de DNS que los configure en hostgator.co pero no me funciona les paso las caputuras para ver si me pueden ayudar ya que railway.app no tiene soporte

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Confiture los DNS tal como me proporciono railway.app y no me funciona

Comment: Ya te sirvio?, como dice en railway los cambios de DNS pueden tardar hasta 72 horas en propagarse, osea en que el dominio que compraste apunte a el de railway

Comment: Ya paso una semana y nada

Answer (score 0):

No sé si sea el caso, o si ya lo solucionaste, pero estoy viendo que el cname pide que sea de nombre de registro @ que sería como apuntar al dominio raíz, y en la imagen que compartes sale www.codera...

Yo recién voy a hacer una personalización de dominio y coloqué el registro con nombre "@"

Quizas eso te ayude.

Answer (score -2):

lo que yo hice fue agregar el dominio en railway, como
*.example.com
y eso nos da configuraciones diferentes que son mas amigables con hostgator

Comment: por que *.example.com ? que es eso ???